Is the "di" in John 7:43 accusative or genitive?
John 7:43

Thus the people were divided because of him.

Does this correlate with Hebrews 1:3 and John 1:3?

Di is not 'accusative'. Di is a preposition. Auton is accusative. Therefore the meaning is 'because of Jesus'. See our previous answers to your previous question.

I suggest you learn a little Greek grammar.

@NigelJ - The Greek does not have "Jesus" but "him". Is this not accusative but genitive?

Yes, indeed. I was giving the ultimate, conceptual meaning of the collocation.

διά is a preposition and so does not have any grammatical case. The meaning of the word is defined by the noun or pronoun which follows it.  When the word is accusative, dia means "because of"; when the word is genitive, dia means "through" or "by the instrumentality of", ie, "caused by".
In the verses nominated by the OP we have:

John 7:43 - αὐτόν is accusative and so the phrase δι’ αὐτόν = "because of Him"
Heb 1:3 - αὐτοῦ is genitive and so the phrase δι’ αὐτοῦ  = "through Him", or, "by Him"
John 1:3 - αὐτοῦ is genitive and so the phrase δι’ αὐτοῦ  = "through Him", or, "by Him"

See BDAG or any other lexicon for more details.

A complete answer has been given by @dottard for the precise question asked.  However, I think I can add an additional response that is more directly related to the science of Hermeneutics.
The OP has asked many questions which focus on the semantics of a preposition (in these instances, διὰ) and its relationship to the Accusative or Genitive cases.  Questions about such relationships are good questions to ask.  However, the answers are quite straight-forward and significant parts of the needed answer are learned by 1st year Greek students in the first few hours of class.  And the answers (such as to this OP question) are readily and easily available with simple Internet searches.  So, they are hermeneutic related questions and answers, but are quite simple.  There’s no fault in simplicity.
It is also obvious that the OP is pursuing a non-Trinitarian, even anti-Trinitarian goal.  While I think that goal is misguided, he certainly has every right to pursue it.  But, this goal is huge.  Many, many people, scholars and layman, people from all over the world representing many languages and cultures, across two millennia have studied, debated, fought and embraced around this Doctrine.  It’s been analyzed from many perspectives across time and space.  To tear down Trinitarianism or to build a non-Trinitarian Doctrine, both, are huge tasks.  Each requires extensive use of hermeneutic tools.  The point being:  The topic is huge.
So, my answer involves suggesting that  the OP is attempting to achieve something extremely large by using extremely simple hermeneutic tools to provide the solution.  And, that won’t work.  The hermeneutic tools needed to achieve such a goal go way beyond what can be learned in the first few hours of a Greek 101 class.
I learned very early on in my Software Engineering career that one had to match the solution to the problem.  If the problem involved a relationship between Invoice and Customer, I had to construct an object that related those two.  If the problem involved a list, I needed a loop.  If the problem was recursive in nature, the algorithm needed to be recursive.  This not only simplified the design, it helped others come up to speed on the implementation since the software matched the real world.  The other benefit was that as the real world changed, the software implementation could track those changes relatively easily.  Exceptions to this rule needed for algorithmic speed needed to be clearly commented.  That is, if the code didn’t communicate, modifying comments were added to the code to make the code clear.  Interestingly, the grammar of a language, in order to support the execution of communication, works the same way.  The way to get from problem to solution needs a proper marrying of tool to task.  Hermeneutics works that same way.
So, if you want to solve what you think is the Trinitarian problem (or any large doctrinal issue), you’re going to need to match the hermeneutic tools to that task.  Asking questions about διὰ plus the accusative is not going to get you there.  Though learning the answer to that basic question, and many other just like it, is a good place to start, the fact is, there’s a long road ahead.  It's not going to work to use the little jeweler's screwdriver to build the 3,500 sq. foot house.  Also, parking on that question isn’t going to move you down the road.  But, for that, you, yourself, will have to dig into learning Greek.  There’s a lot of resources available.
I’ll also offer that Hermeneutics is oriented toward doing research.  It’s not a toolbox where one starts with a solution and grabs the closest tool to “fix the problem”.  What nearly always happens in that case is you grab the hammer and every problem looks like a nail.  The sorry story of Jephthah comes to mind.

you did not answer my question though. I asked why John 7:43 is any different to Hebrews 1:3.

@JoshuaB  As my first sentence states, I refer you to Dottard.  The rest of my answer speaks to there being relatively small elements and relatively large elements in any Art and Science.  Hermeneutics is no different.  You haven't yet grasped the small element, even when answered multiple times by multiple people.  You have been answered.  I will not spend anymore time on this topic (not question, but topic).

Mike Sangrey - After extensive research, I have come to the conclusion that you are right on this particular issue, in that "di autou" is "through him" and "di autou" is "because of him". However, Jesus being the agent of creation does not dent my beloved Unitarian assurance, for it strengthens it. Trinitarians have it wrong.
